# Underscores (_s) modify navigation.js move menu toggle button

Tags: javascript, wordpress, underscores-wp

I am using the _s theme from Wordpress (which I do often), but in my design, I want to move the menu toggle button to another div. I have modified the navigation.js file, but I can't seem to get it to display the menu.

The HTML (a little simplified to remove site-specific data):

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header">
        <div id="site-branding" class="site-branding">
            <h1 class="site-title"><a href="#" rel="home">Site Title</a></h1>   
            <button id="open-menu" class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false"><span class="dashicons dashicons-menu-alt"></span></button>
        </div><!-- .site-branding -->

        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">

            <div id="primary-menu" class="menu">
                <ul class="nav-menu">
                     <li class="page_item page-item-1"><a href="#">Item One</a></li>
                     <li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="#">Item Two</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->

</header>
```

The relevant javascript:

```
( function() {
    const siteNavigation = document.getElementById( 'site-navigation' );
    const container = document.getElementById('site-branding');
    const button = container.getElementsByTagName( 'button' )[ 0 ];

    button.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
        siteNavigation.classList.toggle( 'toggled' );

        if ( button.getAttribute( 'aria-expanded' ) === 'true' ) {
            button.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
        } else {
            button.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'true' );
        }
    } );


}() );
```

I know that the event listener is working (if I add an alert or console.log item, it displays as expected), but the class list doesn't change, nor does the aria-expanded attribute.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you show us the CSS for .toggled? May be it is still dependent on something set in where it originally came from.

Comment: check your css, because this is working : [js fidle](https://jsbin.com/cimarireco/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: @robert yes it is toggling toggled class but we don't know why that isn't showing the menu do we? Maybe I've missed something.

Comment: it is css problem.  id="sideNavigation"  have class "main-navigation" maybe it is this...show us code of css responsible for main-navigation, toggle and #sideNavigation problem is somewhere there

Comment: @robert thanks for that. You're right that it works in the fiddle, but not on the site. I have no idea why, but the "toggled" class does not add / remove on click in my active site. The CSS isn't at issue in this case because the class toggle isn't working.

Comment: put console.log(siteNavigation.classList) in function handling click event

Comment: you taken button[0] ... make more specific selector, probably you have more buttons

Comment: Have done all of this troubleshooting stuff - and also watched the code inspector as I click the button. It is correctly getting the right button (triggering an alert/console log on click works). It is simply not changing the aria-expanded attribute or the primary-menu class. When I (finally) figure it out, I'll let you know!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I was struggeling with it today so I thought I help out anybody still struggeling with it.

In underscores original navigation.js file you can find another click event listener just below the code for the button:

```
document.addEventListener( 'click', function( event ) {
const isClickInside = siteNavigation.contains( event.target );
if ( ! isClickInside ) {
  siteNavigation.classList.remove( 'toggled' );
  button.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
}} );
```

so basically every time you click the button the next thing that happens is that you click outside the siteNavigation container (since you moved the button there) and it toggles the class again :)

hope this helps someone